# Variance and mean for subsets

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean

In an M/G/1 queue, the service time for all customers follows a general distribution. So, it is required to have the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ for them. What if each customer's service time follows a distribution by itself (i.e has a mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$).

What is the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ for the queue? I asuume that:

$\mu=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i}{n}$

What about $\sigma^2$?

Comment: As @pedrosebe explains, if each customer randomly and independently chooses its service time distribution from a set of $n$ given distributions then the service times of the customers are still independent and identically distributed (as required by the M/G/1 model). The mean and variance of this overall service time distribution are as you mention. However, your question leaves open the possibility that the service times are NOT identically distributed. E.g. if arrival 1 has mean $\mu_1$, arrival 2 mean $\mu_2$, ... , arrival $n+1$ mean $\mu_1$ again and so on. Then $M/G/1$ does not apply.

Comment: It does not apply because of n? I'm sorry can you explain?

Comment: What I want to say is: it is not clear from your question whether or not it is an M/G/1 system. You need to specify how exactly the service time of the $i$th customer ($i=1,2,3,\ldots$) is determined.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. The service time is random out of each subset. For example, arrival 1 has a random service time = {x1,x2,...xn} and arrival 2 has a random service time = {y1,y2,...ym}. As you can see arrival 1 has a mean and variance by himself and the same with arrival 2 and so on. I know it's a weird situation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the queue model you mentioned, but this question can be answered using two theorems from general stats.

Your assumption for $\mu$ is correct, due to the [law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). The idea is that when you sample a customer uniformly, the expected waiting time for that customer can be $\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_n$, each with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, the overall expected value is indeed $\mu=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i}{n}$.

For the variance, you should look for the [law of total variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), which states that the overall variance is the sum of the average individual variance (given by $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}{n}$) and the variance between individuals (given by $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mu_i-\mu)^2}{n}$).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't get it. Is the overall variance is the average of individual variances ($\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2}{n}$)? I don't think it's the second one for one reason. What if ($\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=...$) the variance in this case will be 0 although they have different distributions. Right?

Comment: No, the overall variance is not just the average of the variances. It is the average of the variances PLUS the variance of the means, that is: $\sigma^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}{n} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mu_i-\mu)^2}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a reference or a proof that I can use in my research?